# How to use and create tag library for select (combobox) in grails

Tags: grails, enums, taglib

I'm very new to grails, What I want to do is load the data elements from enum class to the select(combo box) then create an tag library for it.

Tag library class

```
package feedback
import imocha.project.Feedback
import imocha.project.FeedbackType

class FeedbackTagLib {
   static namespace = "l"

    def enumFeedbackType ={attrs, body ->
        attrs.name = "type"
        attrs.from = "${FeedbackType.values()}"
        out << g.select(attrs.name, attrs.from, attrs.value, attrs.optionKey)
    }
}
```

Enum class

```
public enum FeedbackType {
    CLA('Complaint'),
    CLE('Complement'),
    ENQ('Enquiry')

    final String value
    FeedbackType(String value){ this.value = value }

    @Override
    String toString(){ value }
    String getKey() { name() }

}
```

I called the tag library in GSP with this

```
<l:enumFeedbackType value="${feedbackInstance?.type}" optionKey ="key" />
```

This is the errors

```
URI /feedback/feedback/create
Class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.select() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, null, null) values: [type, [Complaint, Complement, Enquiry], null, null] Possible solutions: collect(), getOut(), inspect(), every()
```

Comment: you are missing the import statement for your enum

Comment: but it is under src/groovy!? if I am doing import is it like this import src.groovy.FeedbackType? this can't be accepted by the compiler

Comment: you can't import a default package class into a class of non-default package. So, either put your tag-lib into a default package, or the enum into `feedback`

Comment: The import problems solved, but it occurs new issues, Please check my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
def enumFeedbackType ={attrs, body ->
    attrs.name = "type"
    attrs.from = FeedbackType.values()
    out << g.select(attrs)
}
```

Comment: it works, but the value of optionKey ="key" was ignored!!

Comment: I checked the output already if the optionKey was worked, it should return the tag of the selected item, for instance, Complement will be the CLE instead of the complement. But it doesn't so that means it still keep the default one, the toString() one